# Formatting the data of xmltype in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, xmltype

I am pretty new to XML in oracle, i have a very simple requirement.

I have a function that returns XMLTYPE data as
e.g.

```
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <RCODE>FIRST CHECK DATA</RCODE>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <RCODE>SECOND CHECK DATA</RCODE>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <RCODE>THIRD CHECK DATA</RCODE>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

I want to avoid all the tags and display the data in a normal way .
I have tried as

```
DECLARE
l_xmltype XMLTYPE;
l_var VARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN
l_xmltype := getdata(849,20130804);                   

l_var := l_xmltype.extract('*/ROW/RCODE/text()').getstringval();   
END;

OUTPUT:

FIRST CHECK DATASECOND CHECK DATAJOHNSON KOUL
```

I want to display the same as

```
FIRST CHECK DATA

SECOND CHECK DATA

THIRD CHECK DATA
```

How can i give linefeed or add whitespace in between the rows.

**I dont want to save the data in any table.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As one of the approaches you can use [XMLSequence()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions251.htm#i1129570) function, which returns a collection of top-level nodes, and then apply [extractvalue()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions061.htm#i1131042) to get the actual node value. As another approach, and the preferable one(as of oracle 11gr2 the [XMLSequence()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions251.htm#i1129570) has been deprecated), you can use [XMLTable()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions253.htm#CIHGGHFB) function:

Here is a simple function which returns data of `XMLType` data type:

```
SQL> create or replace function GetXML return xmltype
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    return xmltype('<ROWSET>
  5                      <ROW>
  6                        <RCODE>FIRST CHECK DATA</RCODE>
  7                      </ROW>
  8                      <ROW>
  9                        <RCODE>SECOND CHECK DATA</RCODE>
 10                      </ROW>
 11                      <ROW>
 12                        <RCODE>THIRD CHECK DATA</RCODE>
 13                      </ROW>
 14                    </ROWSET>');
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created
```

1. Using `XMLSequence()`

   ```
   select extractvalue(column_value, '/RCODE') as rcode
     from table(
                xmlsequence(
                            extract(getxml, '/ROWSET/ROW/RCODE')
                           )
                )
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   RCODE
   --------------------
   FIRST CHECK DATA
   SECOND CHECK DATA
   THIRD CHECK DATA
   ```
2. Using `XMLTable()`

   ```
   select Rcode
     from xmltable('/ROWSET/ROW/RCODE'
                     passing getxml columns Rcode varchar2(21) path '/RCODE')
   ```

   Result:

   ```
    RCODE
    ---------------------
    FIRST CHECK DATA
    SECOND CHECK DATA
    THIRD CHECK DATA
   ```